# Why are there no AR verbs?

Tags: verbes

Spanish has 3 types of verbs, ar, er, and ir. French has 3 types: er, ir, and re. It looks like French shifted the verb to the right phonetically (if Spanish had a 4th re category, and I mean the vowels a e i o u). I don't speak French but I do speak Spanish occasionally at home. Latin had ar-like verbs too. So, why doesn't French?

Comment: French has 4 infinitive suffixes, not 3 (-er, -oir, -re and -ir). They correspond to the Latin, -āre, -ēre, -ěre and -īre suffixes. Spanish's -ar verbs correspond to fr. -er and la. -āre, -ir verbs to fr. -ir and la. -īre, but it merged both types of -ere suffixes into one: -er (that corresponds to french's -oir and -re verbs both, for example beber/boire or moler/moudre)

Answer (score 4):

French shifted the Latin vowel *a* to *e* in this context. This isn't a change that occurred only in verbs, but in all kinds of words: for example, the adjective *cher* comes from Latin *carus,* and the noun *mer* comes from Latin *mare.*

The general sound change is that Latin *a* in a stressed open syllable (basically, *a* followed by a single consonant and then an unstressed vowel) became French *e* (sometimes spelled *ai*). So the Latin infinitive ending *-are* became the French infinitive ending *-er,* and [the Latin participle ending *-ata* became the French participle ending *-ée*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26305/6881), the Latin second person plural ending *-atis* became the French second person plural ending *-ez,* and so on.